# Throwing an exception named: "Unable to stream pdf: headers already sent" after all whitespaces removed

Tags: php, html, exception

I'm trying to convert HTML To PDF, by copying the whole HTML in the textarea. I've tried all the examples shown in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19524709/dompdf-unable-to-stream-pdf-headers-already-sent) without solving the problem. Why is this happening? Here's my main php file:

```
<?php
use Dompdf\Dompdf;
require 'vendor/autoload.php';
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
    <title>PDF Converter</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div style="text-align: center;">
        <form method="POST">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="convert">Paste Your HTML Code here ; )
                    <hr>
                    <textarea name="htmlCode" class="form-control" rows="10" placeholder="<body>Example..</body>">asd</textarea>
                </label>
            </div>
            <input class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" value="Convert To PDF" name="convert">
        </form>
        <?php
            if (isset($_POST['convert'])) {
                $dompfd = new Dompdf();
                $html = htmlspecialchars($_POST['htmlCode']);
                $dompfd->loadHtml($html);
                $dompfd->setPaper('A4', 'landscape');
                $dompfd->render();
                $dompfd->stream();
            }
        ?>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You output HTML, therefore headers have sent saying it's text/html.

Move your PHP to the top of the script above all HTML and it should work!

exit(); after calling the stream() method too.